# Non clickable object that looks like button in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there an easy (non-hackish?) way to make a Bootstrap button lookalike that's not clickable (and I don't mean a disabled button). Basically a `<div class="btn btn-default">Something</div>` that doesn't behave like a link.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you've put in your question is exactly what you want.. just apply the button styling to a normal div, ie. not an `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've done this before using a new class `btn-static`:

```
.btn-static {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  cursor: default;
}
.btn-static:active {
  -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 0px white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px white;
  box-shadow:         inset 0 0 0px white;
}
```

And use it like the following:

```
<div class="btn btn-static">Static</div>
<!-- btn-default for comparison -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
```

So now it looks like a button, but doesn't act like one when you click it.

[Bootply Link for Example](http://www.bootply.com/zuRqIk0XKF)

Answer (score 5):

As @benrwb mentioned in the comments, the most elegant solution would be to set the elements style property "pointer-events" to "none".

E.g.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">My Button</button>
```

becomes

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="pointer-events: none;">My Button</button>
```

This doesn't only work on Bootstrap buttons, but also every other HTML element that has some kind of hover actions.

Comment: this is a great solution, that preserves the style of the button, while making it not events-fireable! +1

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work too:

`<div class="btn btn-default disabled" style="cursor:default;">Something</div>`

Comment: Instead of `disabled`/`cursor:default` how about `pointer-events: none`? That way the colours aren't changed.

Comment: @benrwb Thanks, that is also a nice solution

Comment: @benrwb: `pointer-events` works perfectly! Why don't you make an answer out of this? (you would have had 6 upvotes already)

Answer (score 0):

```
.btn-block+.btn-block{margin-left:0}
```